# CFForm validation and onclick before submit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, coldfusion, onclick

I have been trying to validate a few fields before submitting a form.  Once the fields are validated by CF I want to pop up a sign in form if the user is not signed in.  However, the problem is that the sign in form is pop up without validation.

inquiry.cfm

```
<cfif not isdefined("form.p1")>
    <cfform name="inquire" action="inquiry.cfm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1">
    <cfinput type="text" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50" required="yes" autofocus="on" validate="email">
    <cfinput type="text" name="subject" size="50" maxlength="50" required="yes" validate="noblanks">
    <cftextarea name="message" cols="45" rows="8" wrap="soft" required="yes" validate="noblanks"></cftextarea>
    <cfif signedin>
        <input type="submit" value=" Send "> 
    <cfelse>
        <input type="submit" value=" Send " onclick="signin(); return false">
    </cfif>
<cfelse>
    do stuff....
</cfif>
```

The "signin" function will pop up the sign in form.

What I have tried so far besides the above:

1. onSubmit instead of onClick.  But I don't want to submit the form until the user is signed in.
2. putting the onClick in the CFFORM tag but CF validation and sign in screen will pop up at the same time.  After dismiss the CF fields validation screen but only complete the sign in screen will submit the blank form i.e. no validation.
3. using CFINPUT tag instead of INPUT. Made no difference but also messed up the button text.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not a different approach?  If the user is not signed in, don't present the form.

Comment: That would be my last option :(

Comment: That should be your first option.

Comment: I don't want to go into details why it is designed this way.  I am sure there must be a way of doing this...

Comment: Change the input in your else condition from type="submit" to type="button".  Have your signin() function launch a modal dialogue window to a CF page that allows buddy to log in.  When he does so, the modal dialogue should close and write back to the original page.  This writing back can either present the submit input or submit the form.

Comment: You can use ajax here. As soon as user finished typing into the input fields. make ajax call to validation.cfm(where your validation sits) and based on return value use your logic

Comment: @DanBracuk Changing the input from submit to button have the same effect.  It won't validate first.  The modal dialogue (signin) window has all the functions that you have mentioned.  It submits the form when login is successful.  Unfortunately, the validation is skipped.

Comment: @Ronnie can you put that as a sample solution so that I can see what you mean?  Thanks.

Comment: Posting the code that submits the form may shed some light on the matter.

Comment: @DanBracuk After the user sign in successfully, the following code is executed to submit the form ->  window.document.forms[0].submit();

Comment: @DanBracuk can you see what else can be done?  btw, I don't know who made the question -1?    I really need it to be resolved but no one seems to know how.

Answer (score 2):

@Jack, This is just an example of form fields validation using ajax. In order to use it you may need to make some changes to it. Moreover, I preferred using html forms in this simple example. 
Let say we have a validatoin.cfc with a method name 'validation' which takes an arg.

```
  <cffunction name="validation" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON" output="false">
    <cfargument name="args" type="any" default="">
   <cfset var retval ='{"return":"false"}'>
    <cfif len(trim(arguments.args))>
        <cfset retval =  '{"return":"true"}'>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn retval>
</cffunction>
```

And here is code for cfm file.

```
    <div  id="target">
  <form name="inquire" action="TestOne.cfm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50" required="yes" autofocus="on" validate="email" ><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="subject" size="50" maxlength="50" required="yes" validate="noblanks" ><br><br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="45" rows="8" wrap="soft" required="yes" validate="noblanks"  ></textarea>
  </form>
  </div>

<script>
    jQuery("#target").on( "click", function(){
        var d = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'validation.cfc?method=validation',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { args: d },
            success: function(data) {
                 if(data.return != 'true'){
                     alert("Please enter an valid email address");                 }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I assume that there is an input with type submit which calls the signin function?  I don't know jQuery so it will be hard for me to modify the code or maintain it :-(